# How to compile botan library on linux in 64-bit mode

Tags: linux, botan

I wanted to compile botan library version Botan-1.10.1 on linux for 64-bit mode.
Please tell me steps for compiling the botan on linux in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 2):

The build instructions for botan can be found here:

http://botan.randombit.net/manual/building.html

Basically, you need to run `./configure`. In theory, it should make an educated guess as to the CPU type, so if you are building on a 64bit machine, it should automagically configure itself accordingly. If not, you can help it along by specifiying the correct cpu type with

`./configure --cpu`

Comment: There are 5 .S files (assembly code which can be preprocessed) 
1. serp_x86_32_imp.S 2. sha1_x86_64_imp.S 3. sha1_x86_32_imp.S
4. md5_x86_32_imp.S 5. md4_x86_32_imp.S 
From naming it can be understood that x86_32 are for 32-bit and x86_64 are for 64-bit.
If I want to compile these .S files into 64-bit then I would require x86_64 files but in Botan-1.10.1 only sha1_x86_64_imp.S which is 64-bit version for sha1_x86_32_imp.S and 64-bit files for rest are not present. I have also checked in latest stable release of botan But not finding the files.
So please tell me how to compile .S files on 64bit

Comment: It should all be taken care of by the build system, as long as you have correctly configured using ./configure . Once you  have configured, just run make. I would also search for a README file

Comment: No worries. Dont forget to vote and accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Botan automatically guesses your OS and architecture. However, you can set that manually if you want(For e.g., if you are targeting multiple platforms or using a script to run configure.py). To build for 64-bit you need to specify `--cpu=x86_64`:

```
python configure.py --cpu=x86_64
```

- To disable certain os features use: `--without-os-features=`.
- To specify compiler use: `--cc=` or `--cc-bin=path/to/compiler`
- To get a single .h and .cpp file use: `--amalgamation`
- To disable certain modules use: `--disable-modules=aes, block`

Further build instructions for botan can be found here or use `--help` to get more info:

http://botan.randombit.net/manual/building.html